# Changing navigation bar color while popping view controller

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar

I have three view controllers. In the first view controller (FirstVC), the navigation bar's bar tint color is clearColor and the bar itself is translucent. When I click on something, I push to SecondVC where the navigation bar needs to be opaque. So I set the barTintColor to some color value and set isTranslucent to false. When I push to ThirdVC from SecondVC, the navigation bar again needs to be translucent. The issue arises when I pop the ThirdVC and go back to SecondVC. The navigation bar appears as transparent for a second and then becomes opaque as required. I'm unable to understand the reason for the delay.

The following method is called from `viewWillAppear()` of SecondVC. I have tried doing the same from the `viewWillDisappear()`of ThirdVC, but to no effect.

```
fileprivate func configureNavigationBar(){

        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(nil, for: UIBarMetrics.default)
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = nil
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = Style.Movie.primaryBackgroundColor
        let titleDict: NSDictionary = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.white]
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = titleDict as? [String:Any]
    }
```

It works fine if I swipe back instead of tapping on the back button.

Comment: are you animating while poping back ??

Comment: nope I'm not doing anything of that sort.

Comment: Even if you manage to implement this, such UI will not look smooth.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

use this function in thiredVC

```
override func willMove(toParentViewController parent: UIViewController?) {
          self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = color use in secondVC
    }
```

Comment: yes this worked.. just that I had to set the isTranslucent property to false as well, along with the barTintColor. Thanks

Comment: You saved my days! Thank you so much!

Comment: Best answer. Thanks

Comment: This worked, but why doesn't the same code work inside viewDidDisappear or viewWillDisappear? And why is it the child view controller's responsibility to set the color and not the parent's responsibility?

Comment: That helped me a looooooot! Thanks :)

Comment: This is called by the VC being pushed, or being popped, and not the one appearing: no way to know why color to show when you pop here since you don't know what you pop to.

Comment: Is there anyway to do this that doesn't rely on a view controller assuming the colour of its parent controller?

Answer (score 5):

Came across this thread and came up with a nice solution to help all in the future.

Firstly create a custom `UINavigationController` with a type `enum` that will help define your navigation setups:

```swift
enum NavType: Int {
    case light, medium, dark
}

class NavigationController: UINavigationController {

    /* 
      Fetch the last controller in the navigation stack so the 
      ViewControllers can switch the navType
    */
    var previousController: ViewController? {
        if viewControllers.count > 1 {
            return viewControllers[viewControllers.count-2] as? ViewController
        }
        return nil
    }

    var navType: NavType = .light {
        didSet { updateNavType() }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
        layoutNavigationTheme()
    }

    func layoutNavigationTheme() {
        switch navType {
        case .dark:
            view.backgroundColor = .white
            navigationBar.backgroundColor = .black
            navigationBar.barTintColor = .black
            navigationBar.tintColor = .white

        ... // Set up as per enum
        }
    }

}
```

Then create a custom `UIViewController` using the `willMove(...`:

```swift
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var navType: NavType = .light

    var navigation: NavigationController? {
        return navigationController as? NavigationController
    }

    // Override willMove will fetch the last controller and set the navType
    override func willMove(toParentViewController parent: UIViewController?) {
        super.willMove(toParentViewController: parent)

        if let navigation = navigation {
            navigation.navType = navigation.previousController?.navType ?? .light
        }
    }

}
```

Then simply in your UIViewControllers, subclass your new `ViewController` and set the `navType` in the `viewDidLoad`:

```swift
class MainController: ViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        navType = .dark
    }

}
```

Comment: Don't just c&p a huge part of the code, spend some more time explaining. And maybe at least sanitise your code first, the comment blocks of `====` characters takes up half the code you posted.

Comment: I hadn't finished what I was posting! @ClausJørgensen

Answer (score 0):

You can make custom navigation bar for SecondVC. And call -popViewController method manually on back button click.

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution that works is overriding pushViewController(_ viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool) and popViewController(animated: Bool) -> UIViewController? of UINavigationController.

```
class CustomNC : UINavigationController {
    public override init(rootViewController: UIViewController) {
        super.init(rootViewController: rootViewController)
    }

    public override init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: Bundle?) {
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    }

    public required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    private var isCustomDesign: Bool { 
        return viewControllers.count == 1 && viewControllers[0] is MyCustomVC // Or any other condition 
    }

    override func pushViewController(_ viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool) {
        super.pushViewController(viewController, animated: animated)
        if isCustomDesign {
            navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.red
        } else {
            navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.green
        }
    }

    override func popViewController(animated: Bool) -> UIViewController? {
        let viewController = super.popViewController(animated: animated)
        if isCustomDesign {
            navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.red
        } else {
            navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.green
        }
        return viewController
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool)
```

You can set your view properties inside that function that will be called when you perform the top viewcontroller pop action.