# UINavigation Title color change issue

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I am facing the navigation title color not change when I pop controller. Please find the below code.

```
ProfilescreenVC.swift
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.white
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.primaryGreen
        let textAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor:UIColor.white]
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = textAttributes
    }
```

EditprofileVC.swift

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()        
        self.style()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func style() {
        navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.black
        navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.white
        let textAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor:UIColor.black]
        navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = textAttributes

        carbonTabSwipeNavigation.setIndicatorColor(UIColor.black)
        carbonTabSwipeNavigation.setTabBarHeight(50.0)
        carbonTabSwipeNavigation.setNormalColor(UIColor.hexString("9A9CA1"), font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 15))
        carbonTabSwipeNavigation.setSelectedColor(UIColor.black, font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 15))

        self.navigationController?.view.setNeedsLayout()
        self.navigationController?.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }

    override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.white
        navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.white
        let textAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor:UIColor.white]
        navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = textAttributes
        super.viewDidDisappear(animated)
    }
```

I have a facing issue with the color changing of the title please check the following [video](https://file.fm/u/skw8j45v#/) for better understanding.

Comment: I think this link will help you
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42618802/changing-navigation-bar-color-while-popping-view-controller

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be some awkward issue in which navigation bar's title attributes are only applied by going forwards.

After trying everything I could I resolved to the following workaround where I provided my own titleView in navigationItem.

```
    let titleView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 50))
    titleView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    let titleLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 50))
    titleLabel.textAlignment = .center
    titleLabel.text = "Profile"
    titleLabel.textColor = .white
    titleView.addSubview(titleLabel)
    self.navigationItem.titleView = titleView
    self.navigationItem.title = "Profile"
```

Note that you also need to provide your title in navigationItem.title so that your back button is set properly when you navigate forward.

Answer (score 0):

```
ProfilescreenVC.swift

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) 
{
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.white
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.primaryGreen
        let textAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor:UIColor.white]
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = textAttributes
    }
```

and in editProfileVC

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) 
        {
    navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.black
            navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.white
            let textAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor:UIColor.black]
            navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = textAttributes
    }
```

No need to add `ViewDidDisapper` in your code